How to set the SP certificate in google as IdP with SAML?
I want to use google as an IdP for SPs using SAML. I have integrated an SP with google as IdP and for this I have followed the documentation provided by google at Google SAML.
I have created my custom SAML app in the Apps and then Web and mobile apps section of the admin console.
The application (SP) performs the SAML flow correctly with google as IdP but I have not seen any section in the admin console when creating my custom SAML app to specify the certificate with which the SP signs the AuthnRequest so google IdP does not validate the AuthnRequest (it only asks for the ACS URL and the Entity ID). So I have the following doubts:

How can I make google IdP to require that the SPs must send signed messages and I can specify or upload the certificate of the corresponding SP so google can check the signature of the message?

The bindings I am using are Redirect and Post binding. With google can I also use Artifact Binding? When downloading the metadata this binding is not included but I don't know if it can be added in the admin console so that it can be used in the SPs.


Thanks for your help
